# Handling entity changes in an information request application

Tags: jpa, model

I have an information request system in place within my web application to allow users to ask questions about a supplier's offers. The implementation is written in Java with JPA. Suppliers can register their offers and potential customers can view them and ask questions or request the services.

I chose to create orders with relationships with customer, offer and supplier. These orders cannot be "archived" because they are permanently live, ie a user can get back to the request at any time and ask questions.

It works fine until the supplier decides to remove the offer (or modify it significantly). As the offer is now linked to requests, I cannot remove it anymore. In any case I would like the user to keep access to these requests even if the offer doesn't exist anymore.

To solve this problem I am now thinking about having two type of request entities, one which is a live version and one which is an "archived" version. The archive version would remove the link to the offer and replace it with a textual form.

I would be very grateful is someone has had to solve a similar problem before and was able to explain how they solved it.

Comment: seems quite typical 'offer state', implemented as enum or relation to State' class, filtered on application level (not JPA). What do you mean "until the supplier decides to remove the offer (or modify it significantly)"? What is 'small' or 'significantly' change?

Comment: anything that would make the request meaningless. I think we should focus on remove for now, easier. I have state (status) indeed, however the problem is the foreign key to the offer object which has been removed. I think I need to remove the relationship and replace it with a text version.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to manage different versions of the entity (your offer). A (significant) change to the entity creates a new version. In your case the new version does not inherent the links.
The system can decide whether a change is significant, e.g. if certain attributes were modified or a modification was large (e.g. the difference in price) or the user (supplier in this case) decides whether her change is big enough to create a new version.
Usually the newest version of your offer entity is accessed. But a link points to a certain version, which is loaded when someone accesses the link.